# How to get a Regex to Match the following String-

Tags: regex

I have the following that needs to be matched.

[item[Some Item Name]] [item[AnotherItem]]

I need a regex to match both of those, so far I came up with

```
(?<=[A-z]\[)([A-z]*)(?=\]\])
```

However it doesnt seem to match the first condition because of the spaces, can anyone help point me in a better direction?

Edit : The expected output should be

```
"Some Item Name" "AnotherItem"
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get as output?

Comment: "Some Item Name" and "AnotherItem"

Sorry I should have clarified that.

Comment: Why not just add space to your character class? Note that `A-z` includes a lot of characters you probably don't want, you should either use `[A-Za-z]` or `[A-Z]` with the ignore case (`i`) flag

Comment: I'm pretty new at learning Regex. I didint know A-z includes other characters. It seems to work with [A-Za-z ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS expression, `/(?<=\[)([a-zA-Z ]*?)(?=\])/g` would do the job.

To check the regex, open the browser console and type in `'[item[Some Item Name]] [item[AnotherItem]]'.match(/(?<=\[)([a-zA-Z ]*?)(?=\])/g)`.